# Why does my img element can't load a path (src) from an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, src

I want to create a slide show. For that to happen I need my image element to pick up src from script but it doesn't. When I write src right there in img element it works but when I write that exect same path in array and try to load it from there using document.nameWrittenInImg.src = "theNameOfTheArray[theIndex]" it can't load the picture.

```
let slideIndex = 0;
let imagesEl = []
imagesEl[0] = 'pictures\towerbridge.png';
imagesEl[1] = 'pictures\puente.png';
imagesEl[2] = 'pictures\rialto.png';
function changeImg() {
    document.slide.src = imagesEl[slideIndex];
    if (slideIndex < imagesEl.length - 1) {
        slideIndex ++;
    } else {
        slideIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

This is from my script file.

In html besides everything else I have:

```
<img name="slide" width="50%" height="50%" alt="slide">
```

It needed to work by pressing a button. I called the function (changeImg()) to check but it doesn't work.

Comment: `document.getElementById('slide').src = `...; You can't just reference an HTML element directly from `document`, you need to query it somehow. Either by using `getElementById` or `querySelector`.

Comment: @ErikTerwan he is using name actually, not Id.

Comment: @ErikTerwan "_You can't just reference an HTML element directly from document_" - [You can...](https://jsfiddle.net/1xrjtpfa/)

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, but the paths are most likely not what you expect them to be. You need to escape backslashes in string literals in JavaScript. So instead of `pictures\towerbridge.png` use `pictures\\towerbridge.png`

Comment: The path separator looks a little off: are you serving the page through a server? You should probably use forward slashes.

Comment: Use `pictures\\towerbridge.png` or just `pictures/towerbridge.png` because the `\t` will be interpreted as a `tab` and your path will be not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using `name` is deprecated and you should use the `id` instead. Then you can use `document.getElementById()` to get the element. But your code works fine except...

... for the fact that your string `'pictures\towerbridge.png'` is likely misunderstood by the browser, as `\` is an escape character and `\t` turns into a [tab]. So the path you're trying to load for the image is actually `pictures owerbridge.png`. To fix this, either use `\\` to escape the backslash, or switch to `/` which should be understood correctly by all browsers.